# Can anyone suggest the best transliteration library to Marathi from English or Marathi written in English?

Tags: python, nlp, libraries, transliteration, indic

I tried using indic-transliteration library but it doesnt work with marathi and the only other possible option I found was google translate API which has a lot of time lag.

I tried using this but my output is different with a "B"

```
import codecs,string
from indic_transliteration import sanscript
from indic_transliteration.sanscript import SchemeMap, SCHEMES, transliterate

def is_hindi(character):
    maxchar = max(character)
    if u'\u0900' <= maxchar <= u'\u097f':
        return character
    else:
        print(transliterate(character, sanscript.ITRANS, sanscript.DEVANAGARI)) 

character = 'Bakrya vikne ahe'
is_hindi(character)

Output:

Bअक्र्य विक्ने अहे
```

Comment: what is your desired output ?? `बक्र्य विक्ने अहे``

Comment: @Ajay Yess, its the ouptut I want

Comment: `character = 'bakrya vikne ahe'`

Comment: Alright, thanks will convert to lower case to make it work! Thanks a lot

Comment: for marathi try `polyglot`

Comment: Okay will try that library

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Polyglot](https://pypi.org/project/polyglot/). As far as transliteration it supports 69 languages.As per [documentation](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Transliteration.html#languages-coverage) it supports Marathi(#47).
There is one more older [module](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).
Update:
with the given module try using `lowercase` .There is no detailed explanation in the docs.

`character = 'bakrya vikne ahe'`

Comment: I have updated with a code, pls have a look at the output and let me know If you can help me.